# org.hibernate.MappingException only when trying to use Hibernate Console perspective

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I've three persistent classes which work well. Now, I'm trying to use Hibernate Console perspective in order to visualize the relationships between them. So I tried configuring using Hibernate Configuration Console, as mentioned [here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html-single/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/index.html#console_conf).

However, I get this error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.org.asterisk.dynamic.realtime.SipFriendsRow"/>
```

Please note, I'm already using and the following code

```
new AnnotationConfiguration()
        .configure()
        .buildSessionFactory();
```

It works executes well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Hibernate annotation library

Or

Add the dependency in Maven’s pom.xml

> ```
>  <dependency>
>     <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
>     <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

You may need to include the JBoss repository in order to download the Hibernate annotation library.

> ```
> <repositories>
> <repository>
>   <id>JBoss repository</id>
>   <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
> </repository>
> ```

1. Use AnnotationConfiguration to build session factory

Normal Hibernate XML file mapping is using Configuration()

> return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

For Hibernate annotation, you have to change it to “AnnotationConfiguration”

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```